# How to call SQL Server stored procedure with datetime parameter from VBA?

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, datetime

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that accepts two input parameters of `datetime` datatype. I want to call it from Excel VBA.

VBA doesn't have a datetime type so I've tried something like this:

```vb
Dim spCommand As ADODB.Command
Set spCommand = New ADODB.Command
spCommand.ActiveConnection = cnn
spCommand.CommandText = "myProcedureName"
spCommand.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
spCommand.Parameters.Refresh
spCommand.Parameters(1).Value = "6/1/2016"      'DateValue("2016-06-01") + TimeValue("00:00:00")
spCommand.Parameters(2).Value = "6/1/2016"     'DateValue("2016-06-01") + TimeValue("23:59:59")
spCommand.Execute
```

But I get this error:

[image]

How can I solve it?

EDIT 1
After followeing what @Joe suggested, I opened my debugger and get this, but error is still there:

[image]

Comment: Did you try the date formatted with # around it? e.g. 6/1/2016, would be #6/1/2016#.

Comment: @RyanWildry. Yes, I did

Comment: @RyanWildry - see updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DateSerial function:

```
spCommand.Parameters(1).Value = DateSerial(2016,1,6)
```

and, if you need it, optionally the TimeSerial function:

```
spCommand.Parameters(2).Value = DateSerial(2016,1,6) + TimeSerial(23,59,59)
```

> VBA doesn't have a datetime type

Yes, it does:

```
Dim dtDateTime as Date
dtDateTime = DateSerial(2016,1,6) + TimeSerial(23,59,59)
```

**UPDATE**

Following your edit, I see that the Parameters collection has three items.  The first is a return parameter, and the second and third are input parameters of type adDBTimeStamp.

Also the `Command.NamedParameters` property is false, so you probably can't use named parameters as you seem to be attempting to do in the screenshot accompanying your edit.

**UPDATE 2**

<s>VBA collections are indexed starting at 1, not 0, so you should be specifying your parameters as:</s>

```
spCommand.Parameters(2).Value = ...
spCommand.Parameters(3).Value = ...
```

I think the above is wrong.  Standard VB/VBA collections are indexed, starting at 1.  I believe the rationale, mistaken in my view, was that 1-based indexes are "more intuitive".

When ADO was developed, I believe Microsoft realized that 1-based collections had been a mistake, and decided to make ADO collections 0-based.  This makes them inconsistent with standard collections, but "more intuitive" to, say, javascript developers.  What an inconsistent mess.

If I'm right (and it's a long time since I used ADO, and I haven't tested this), then you need:

```
spCommand.Parameters(1).Value = ...
spCommand.Parameters(2).Value = ...
```

which should eliminate your 3265 error, but doesn't solve your original problem.  Your debug trace appears to show that the parameters have been set to the expected values.  I can only suggest you try to generate an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including a simplified version of the Stored Procedure in question.

Comment: Thanks @Joe but it doesn't work for me! I get the same error.

Comment: @baudo2048 - 80040e14 is a generic error.  Try running under the debugger, and inspect the parameters collection after calling refresh to make sure the data types are what you expect.

Comment: I've tried what you suggest in your UPDATE but it doesn't work, I get another error: runtime error '3265'. I upvote your answer because it solve datetime matter. I think there's something else, maybe a silly mistake in order to solve the question. That first @RETURN_VALUE is strange, my stored procedure doesn't return any value. Thanks